# Is it possible to concatenate a function input to text of another function call?

Tags: javascript

Firstly appologies for the poor title, not sure how to explain this in one line.

I have this Javascript function (stripped down for the purpose of the question)...

```
function change_col(zone){

    var objects= zone1227.getObjects();

}
```

I am passing in an integer into the function. Where I have "zone1227", I want that 1227 to be the integer I pass in.

I've tried this;

`var zonename = "zone" + zone;`

`var objects= zonename.getObjects();`

but that doesn't work.

Is this possible? The functions do exist for every possible integer passed in, but I was hoping to keep the code compact rather than a long list of if statements with hardcoded function names.

Comment: Let me just say this is undoubtedly an incorrect way to architect your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `zone1227` is apparently a global variable, it can also be written as `window.zone1227` or as `window['zone1227']`. This means that you *can* achieve what you describe, by writing this:

```
function change_col(zone){

    var objects= window['zone' + zone].getObjects();

}
```

Nonetheless, I agree with Interrobang's comment above. This is not a good way to accomplish whatever it is that you *really* want to accomplish. You should not be referring to global variables via strings containing their names.

Answer (score 0):

<s>No, you cannot refer to a variable with the value of a string, nor can you concatenate anything onto a variable name.</s> EDIT: turns out you can. You still shouldn't.

Yes, you can avoid using a long hard-coded if/elseif sequence: use an array.

Then you can say this:

```
function change_col(arr, i)
{
    var objects= arr[i].getObjects();
}
```

And the call would be something like:

```
change_col(zone, 1227);
```